# php://input direct to browser

Tags: php, upload, esp32

Hooked up an ESP32cam as a client. Uploading a Jpeg every 20sec to my server.

Using

```
$received=file_get_contents('php://input');
$fileToWrite = "name ".time().".jpg";
file_put_contents($fileToWrite, $received);
```

i am able to store the incoming Jpeg on my server nicely. Everything peachy

There is no way I am able to directly display the incoming/uploaded JPEG in my browser. Without storing the image.

I tried

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg'); 
echo readfile($received);
```

with and without the echo, I tried base_64encoding, decoding, imagejpeg and imagecreatefromjpeg. The latter is complaining that I need an actual name and folder in order to use it. With only a variable that is not going to work....

According to the clientside I am uploading something, but in every case it is  between 429 and 433 bytes.
The browser says "the image  cannot be displayed because it contains errors"
This is the monitor output of my client:

```
HTTP_EVENT_ON_HEADER, key=Content-Length, value=429
12:48:11.663 -> HTTP_EVENT_ON_HEADER, key=Content-Type, value=image/jpeg
12:48:11.663 -> HTTP_EVENT_ON_DATA, len=377
12:48:11.696 -> HTTP_EVENT_ON_DATA, len=52
12:48:11.696 -> HTTP_EVENT_ON_FINISH
12:48:11.696 -> esp_http_client_get_status_code: 200
12:48:11.696 -> HTTP_EVENT_DISCONNECTED
```

When actually storing the image, the amount of HTTP_EVENT_ON_DATA are way more (duhhh) than when trying to directly display the image in the browser.

Anyone an idea what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. Am I correct in that you have a cam that uploads images to your server? And then you're accessing a page on that server through the browser and expect the image to show up? Even though you never stored it on the server?

Comment: `$received` _is_ your binary image data already, so using `readfile($received)` of course makes zero sense. You want simply `echo $received;` …

Comment: @magnus: that is correct. Expecting that the $received, that is working when stroring it, works when displaying it.

Comment: @04FS: tried that too....:-((

Comment: Try like this, I hope this will work: `list($originalWidth, $originalHeight) = getimagesize($received);
        $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($received);
        $img = imagecreatetruecolor(100, 100);
        ImageCopyResampled($img, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 100, $originalWidth, $originalHeight);
        header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
        ob_start();
        imagejpeg($img);
        $size = ob_get_length();
        header("Content-Length: " . $size);
        ob_end_flush();
        imagedestroy($img);`

Comment: I think the issue is a misunderstanding of how PHP works. If you make a request to a PHP file, any variables etc you create during that request (like your upload) will only be available in that specific request, unless you store the data somewhere (ex. file system, cache, db). When you make your next request using the browser, nothing from the previous request will exist.

Comment: If you don't care about saving the files, just save them with the same name: "foo.jpg" on the server. Now you should be able to load the same file name all the time but will get the updated image. If you want to keep the images, store them in a folder with your current naming convention and just fetch the last image in that folder (could end up with a lot of files though)

Answer (score 0):

It is not the solution I imagined, but i'll store the image with the same name every 20 sec. like @Magnus Eriksson suggested.

I will also try to store in cache and 'tinker' around.
Unfortunately the solution @udit-rawat suggested did not work.

Thanks